# How to solve threading sync issues with unknown number of events in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, events

We're using WebClient `DownloadDataCompleted` & `DownloadProgressChanged` events. We noticed that the progress event can fire an indeterminate number of times and not return from each callback, and still the `DataCompleted` event will fire. The reason `DownloadProgressEvent` doesn't return is because it's updating the `ProgressBar` on the form, which is going through a `Control.Invoke` cycle. We don't use `BeginInvoke` for other reasons (`ProgressBar` max and min change constantly and this cause assertions, since we can't sync up progress updates with progress bar max/min settings).

The question is: Whats the best approach for this?

Simply put, we don't want to acknowledge a completed download until the `ProgressBar` finishes updating. This implies something of a reverse semaphore that counts up, and is set when it goes back down to zero. We could just use a counter to increment/decrement when entering/leaving `DownloadProgress` callback, but I would have thought there's something more OS specific.

Comment: Your progress event-handler doesn't need to `Control.Invoke()`.

Comment: @Henk: I couldn't in MSDN find any guarantees about the thread where the events should be fired. (Looked [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddatacompleted.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx).)

Comment: Actually it does. WebClient is created on another thread.

Comment: "We don't use BeginInvoke" - maybe you are.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the following:

```
DownloadDataCompleted += delegate {
    progressBar.Invoke(() => {
        progressBar.Value = progressBar.Maximum;
        progressFinished = true;
    }
};

DownloadProgressChanged += delegate {
    progressBar.Invoke(() => {
        if (!progressFinished)
            progressBar.Value =
                  progressBar.Minimum +
                  (progressBar.Maximum - progressBar.Minimum) * progressRatio;
    }
};
```

There should be no problems with changing the Maximum and Minimum, since all the changes occur anyway in the UI thread.

(The code which changes `Maximum` or `Minimum` must take care about recalculating the `Value`, of course.)

P.S.: Edited the post, taking @Ben Voigt's suggestion into account.

Comment: You don't need some special `SafeInvoke` method, `Control.Invoke` already checks whether it's on the right thread and simply calls the delegate directly if it is.

Comment: @Ben: thanks for the hint, I'm not really experienced with winforms. Is the behaviour of `Dispatcher.Invoke` in WPF the same? I'm used to writing something like `if (dispatcher.CheckAccess()) { /*call directly*/ } else { dispatcher.Invoke(...); };` -- which seems to be not needed?

Comment: We're basically doing this via Control.Invoke. The problem is 'Invoke' is needed because the webclient is created on another thread (which we need to do to monitor other windows type events). For reasons that are not clear, when Control.Invoke is invoked the webclient thread keeps going, calling the download progress event while still inside the previous Control.Invoke call. To make it more difficult, the DownloadComplete event will be called before the first downlaodprogress event even returns.

Comment: @Gio: with the proposed code, all the logic is done in the UI thread, so it's guaranteed to be serial.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use BeginInvoke to handle the control update, but arrange for the an atomic update of fields holding the requested "current" and "maximum" values, along with a flag that indicates an update has been requested.  The UI's update routine should not hold any locks while performing the update.  If locks are used, the UI should grab the lock, make a local copy of the values (including the flag), clear the flag, release the lock, and redraw if necessary.  The routine (on the other thread) which wants to request the update should grab the lock, update the values, and--if the flag isn't already set--set the flag and perform a BeginInvoke.

That will ensure that no matter how often the non-UI thread requests an update, at most one BeginInvoke will be outstanding.  Further, every update will have usable values for "current" and "maximum".

Comment: You don't actually need any locks, because the work with UI controls must take place in the UI thread, so it's synchronized anyway.

Comment: @Vlad: The idea is that there are a couple of fields which would hold the *desired* "current" and "maximum" values for the controls; these values could be updated on *any* thread, subject to locking requirements.  A thread which updates these variables should check whether an update is already pending and, if not, call BeginInvoke to request one.  Controls which accept input from a user should generally have synchronous semantics, but for those which do not (like progress indicators) it's often better to have asynchronous semantics.

Comment: @Vlad: Among other things, when code outside the UI thread is performing a task about which progress should be reported, it should generally not concern itself with how often to report updates.  The code should call the "update" routine any time it has something to report, and let the "update" routine itself worry about when or how the screen should get updated to reflect such progress.  In some cases, the optimal behavior will be for the update object to have a timer; when a request is received, if the timer isn't running it redraws the object and starts the timer.

Comment: If the timer is running, the update routine exits but leave the "pending" flag set; when the timer expires, it checks the pending flag and--if it's set--performs the update.  If the timer interval is e.g. 100ms, then if two updates are received 25ms apart, the first will happen immediately but the second won't.  If no other update request arrives within 75ms after the second one (100ms of the first), the second will be processed.  Otherwise the second update request will be effectively discarded without being processed.